# Jprofiler crash

Tags: java, weblogic, performance-testing, jprofiler

I was trying to configure jProfiler with remote Weblogic server in a solaris box. The Server starts up with properly, however when I attach the jProfiler GUI to the server the following error comes up and the server crashes. tmp directory has sufficient access and space. I can see some of the files such as jpcOYaysx are created in tmp directory. Can someone help me on how to solve this? Do we have logs specific to jProfiler, how to configure it?

```
JProfiler> Reconnection.
JProfiler> Could not open config file: /tmp/jpcOYaysx
```

I cannot find any help pages / documents for editing jProfiler config.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you have enough memory on profiling machine ?
How big is your VM size on Weblogic server ?
I would suggest to decrease it during profiling to 1 GB.